# ElasticSearch failed to start: AssertionError while creating Node object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm trying to create a Node object using below environment settings-
environment settings:

```
 Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("http.cors.enabled", "true")
            .put("path.data", "target/es-data_" + UUIDs.randomBase64UUID().toLowerCase())
            .put("path.home", "target/es-home_" + UUIDs.randomBase64UUID().toLowerCase())
            .put("cluster.name", "testCluster")
            .put(NetworkModule.HTTP_TYPE_KEY, "netty4")
            .put("http.port", 9200)
            .build();
 private static class ElasticNode extends Node {
        public ElasticNode(Settings settings, Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> classpathPlugins) {
            super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(settings,new HashMap<>(), null, () -> "node1"), classpathPlugins, false);
        }
        
    }
```

ElasticSearch version 7.17.10,
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation,
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-67-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "UNIX"

and getting the following error:-

```
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    #14 85.59   at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getControlGroups(OsProbe.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.10.jar:7.17.10]
```

what I'm missing in the config? Please help!

Comment: It fails [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7f1b183978dd78bbcd1bfe81ba60faba66c49264/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/monitor/os/OsProbe.java#L262) while trying to parse content of `/proc/self/cgroup` and not finding 3 fields separated by `:`.  Running embedded elasticsearch is quite tricky in the recent versions of elasticsearch. What is your goal here? Are you doing it for testing or it is meant for production?

Comment: I'm doing it for testing, could you tell me how to configure /proc/self/cgroup or any way to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

For integration testing my suggestion would be to start elasticsearch externally. For example, you can configure it using docker compose and spawn it before running your tests. Alternatively, you can spawn elasticsearch as a separate process from your test or from gradle (if you are good with it). There is just way too much stuff happening during the node bootstrapping process to try replicating it in your code.

Even elasticsearch project itself is spawning elasticsearch cluster in a special gradle tasks. By the way this task is available in their test framework, so you can use their gradle build plugin to incorporate such task in your project. Here is an example of how to do that - https://github.com/imotov/esitsandbox